# rake db:structure:dump results in mysqldump: Error: 'Access denied;you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

In upgrading ruby to 2.7.1, while keeping mysql2 gem at '~> 0.5.3' I ran into a problem.
rake db:migrate (or rather rake db:structure:dump) produces
mysqldump: Error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces

this is connecting to a testing env database from a docker container, don't see how that matters, but just FYI. Connecting to my local db it works fine for both rake db:migrate and rake db:structure:dump

Mysql version is mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33 in both environment and has not been changed in the past forever